# .NET 32-bit dev vs. 64-bit prod

Tags: .net, asp.net, sqlite, 64-bit

This question is kind of related to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524837/32-bit-build-server-and-64-bit-production-server-for-net-web-apps) but I have a specific scenario in mind.

We do our development on 32-bit machines and deploy to a 64-bit server.  The application is an ASP.NET Web Application and we use SQLite for the backend of this application.  When I try to build on the remote machine I get errors from MSBuild saying it cannot find the DLL.

The web application needs to be able to launch 64-bit processes (because these processes need lots and lots of memory!)

I have seen solutions where you simply put IIS into 32-bit mode and run everything in 32-bit mode to be able to use SQLite, but does this screw me out of being able to launch a 64-bit process??

Help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you put IIS in 32bit mode you won't get 64bit processes.  If you want the database to run in-process with your app, you'll need to choose a database with a 64bit provider - perhaps [sql server compact edition](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx).

Alternatively, considering your purported RAM needs it sounds like maybe what you should really do is move to a full out-of-process server-class database engine like SQL Server Express or Standard.

Comment: Thanks Joel,  The web application is basically a workflow management tool.  It starts other processes and these other processes need the memory, not the web app (or the database itself).  I might give SQL Server Compact or Express a try though. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the managed version of SQLite built in .NET?  That may solve your problems.

http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/

Nick